# Momentum gain of a square loop when switching of a wire causing magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

> A square frame made of wire with diameter $d_0$ is placed near a long straight wire carrying current $I_0$. When this current is turned off, a momentum $p_0$ is imparted to the frame. What momentum would be imparted to the frame if the initial current is $3I_0$ and diameter of the wire is $2d_0$
>
> [image]

My conceptual doubts:

- As the current is turned off, the magnetic field and magnetic flux in the downward direction decrease.
- This should induce a current in the wire(if it is conducting)
  Since it is not given that the wire is conducting, should it gain a momentum in the downward direction instead of a charge flowing?

Which equations would apply here that would lead me to an answer?

Comment: I don't understand why is momentum imparted instantenously when the current is switched off...

Comment: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/23-2-faradays-law-of-induction-lenzs-law/ This article explains how change in energy/ flux is not instantaneous.( Read the "Conservation of Energy" section.)So switching current off should induce current and hence momentum on the wire.

Comment: I understand the instantaneousness property now, I never put much attention to that particular point before... but still, I don't undertand why the energy must be transfered in way of momentum. In sense, couldn't the energy be transferred in some other form?

Comment: I've posted this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/650729/energy-conservation-transit-time). However, I am still unsure about the momentum claim, if you could show a related question which uses similar concept to solve from some standard text, that'd be nice.

Comment: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/22-7-magnetic-force-on-a-current-carrying-conductor/ I assume you are aware of this concept. A current carrying wire in a magnetic field experiences force. Hence there is change in momentum. The accepted answer to this question also leads to that final step for finding the momentum imparted.

Comment: To simplify, change in flux leads to induced emf that induced emf leads to induced current, that current now generated force on square wire and that force finally gives a momentum to the wire.

Comment: See the force exists due to the wire existing, as soon as you remove it, I see no reason for there be a sudden impulsive rise in the momentum. Maybe you are saying that the different part of loop cause force on each other, but that too I disagree, because the net sum of internal forces must be zero if one were to consider the whole square loop.

Comment: the force exists as long as there is magnetic field and the induced current due to change in magnetic flux. When the flux has finally dropped to zero, the wire stops gaining momentum as now there is no change in flux. And the total forces on the whole square loop is not zero as the magnetic is varying is varying over the wire with distance. The net force is towards left and it is only due to the vertical wires. The forces on horizontal wires cancel each other But the vertical wires dont as B in inverserly proportional to distance from long straight wire.

Comment: I think I understand you now, you are saying the $B$ takes some time to die off, in this time due to the force on length of conductor, the loop accelerates. I've asked this question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/650736/why-does-an-impulsive-force-come-about-when-switching-of-a-current-carrying-wire)

Comment: yes you are right, atleast that's what i understand about electromagnetic induction btw did you check this, i attached it earlier comments, it will clear your confusions you asked in a recent question. https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/22-7-magnetic-force-on-a-current-carrying-conductor/

Comment: I had skimmed through it but I felt it didn't contain sufficient discussion on what my doubt was. Maybe I have missed something, if you could quote what part you wanted me to see specifically then I may get it.

Comment: Basically, every current carrying wire in a magnetic field experiences forces. We can calculate that by $F=I. (L×B) $. Here in this particular question The $I$ is Induced current. This is an impulsive force as it acts for a short time. It gone after the B part becomes Zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127414/discussion-between-buraian-and-tanisha-daharwal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the wire must be conducting according to the context of the question. Without a conducting loop , momentum will be not be imparted as far as the given system in question is concerned.

First of all, due to change in flux, a current will be induced.
A current carring wire(each side of square can be considered as a straight current carrying wire) in presence of a magnetic field( in this case,due to the long straight wire) experiences a force , which is due to the change in momentum.

Flux φ can be calculated by ∫B.da  (Remember B will vary with distance here).

Induced current I= E/R , E=dφ/dt  R is assumed to be the resistance of wire.

Force experience by wire= ILB (Again, B will vary,and think where force will be applied and where not due to direction of current).

Momentum imparted can be calculated  by 'solving' the equation F= dP/dt

Comment: thanks a lot, nicely explained!