# Why does an impulsive force appear when switching of a current carrying wire near a loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

I'm trying to understand the set up of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/650432/how-to-solve-this-problem-on-electromagnetic-induction?noredirect=1#comment1461141_650432), my doubt is simply why does a sudden impulsive force appear when switch off the current carrying wire?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current is turned off at time $t=0$, it means that
$$I(t) = \begin{cases} I_0,  & t \leq 0 \\ 0, & t \gt 0
\end{cases}$$

Next, we need to assume that the propagation of electromagnetic signals is instantaneous. In other words, the size of the setup is much less than a typical value of $ct$. The magnetic field is proportional to $I(t)$, and the induced current in the loop is proportional to the time derivative of the magnetic field. Therefore, the induced current is proportional to the time derivative of $I(t)$, which is
$$\frac{\text{d}{I}}{\text{d}t} = -I_0 \delta(t)$$

The force on the loop is proportional to the induced current in the loop (an integral), so it contains a $\delta(t)$ term and is therefore an instantaneous impulse. The momentum, which is the integral of the force over time, is finite.